# how to destory the select2 picker in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$('select.select2_demo_3').select2("destory");
```

In the above jQuery I destroy the select picker but it throws an error like below.

> VM648:301 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function

Comment: I think the problem is the way you include your select2 js code and your jquery. please include all relevant code

Comment: Make sure that you are including jQuery before select2 plugin.

Comment: `dest**or**y` or `dest**ro**y` ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you include Select2 on your website?

Include the following lines of code in the  section of your HTML.

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: select2.min.css and select2.min.js

Answer (score 0):

if your goal is to destroy a select option with a class ="select2", 
what you can do is something like this

```
 $('.select2').remove();
```

Comment: I am not asking remove the select picker destroy the select2 picker